# how can i get real path in image gallery?

Tags: android

I got all images from device's gallery,but i got images path is like `content://media/external/image/media/102`,so i want to get real image path for each images and send email,how can i get path?given below code i used,anybody knows,please give some sample code for me..i have email code.i want to only get real image path.How can I convert this path to real one (just like '`/sdcard/image.png'`) ?

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri photoUri = data.getData();
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor actualimagecursor = managedQuery(photoUri, proj,null, null, null);
int actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); actualimagecursor.moveToFirst();
String img_path = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
```

it work well..